# Running a Java application in a network location

Tags: java, networking, deployment

We have a VPN network and at a central point we have kept a java application (.jar file). We are allowing users of the VPN system to use this application- What are the cons of using this solution?

As for pros -

1. Easy to update to a new version
2. Storing the files in relative location helps save files in a central location

### EDIT

Is it possible to access the COM ports using JWS since our app runs inside a sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you describe would work well with Java Web Start - advantages I can think of

- reduced bandwidth usage (JWS will only download files if they have been updated, if not it will use a local cached copy).
- possibility to use specific JVM parameters.
- automatic check of the client configuration (for example, JRE version must be at least xxxx, if not download it).

There are probably more.

Comment: I would add that as the app must run in the JWS sandbox (limited functionality) for security. Or you have to sign the jars for full Java Api. Since I guess you want an easy process, you can self-sign the jars.

Comment: @Duli-chan I have no idea but [this page](http://vamsinotes.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/java-web-start.html) seems to show how to do it. If you already have the code for it, it should not be too complicated to test if it works. I think you need to sign your jars for it to work.

Comment: another problem is I use a lot of libraries...(Maven). Do I need to sign all the jars?

Comment: Yes - I use an ant script that does it for me. Not sure how to do it with maven.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay. For a customer project, we choosed this solution too.
Its okay, if you have a good bandwith and, on traffic producing apps, a low latency at runtime.

For a test, I build a Sql-Wrapper, to add a simulated latency to each call to our database. So we're got a feeling for the application at runtime without a real vpn connection.